# How do I programmatically scale or pinch in flutter?

Tags: flutter, scaling, gesture

I have a screen that uses gestures to do some calculations in onScaleUpdate. Now I'd like to manually call onScaleUpdate when certain action is performed, how can I do it?

I tried to use flutter driver to achieve my goal but I don't think it's the right way to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)